# Azure App Service Memory Working Set steady at 0 bytes

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-monitoring, .net-4.6.1

We have an S3 app service running in Azure and deploy updates every other Wednesday night.

After last night's update (no change in any framework or nuget packages) our Memory working set, for the first time in several years, remains at 0 bytes.

We have been seeing some performance issues over the past year or so, but have mostly gotten them under control.

What would cause the memory working set to bottom out like this?

In the screenshot, you can see where the memory working set is constantly at 0 bytes after last night's deployment (deployed 2022-04-06 @ 10:30PM CST), and only spikes occasionally.

48 hour, 1 min increment Memory working set avg vs Private bytes avg
[image]